# Reconciliation of data

Tags: mysql, sql-server, etl, talend

I have a ETL which loads delta data from a table on sql server to a table in mysql. The load runs to extract the data between yesterday and today and puts this data into mysql

However, this runs fine for a few days and after a few days I get the problem of some rows missing. How do I reconcile the data under such circumstances? Is it a practice to truncate load the table once in a week or something?

Comment: Perhaps your ETL tool should be performing a lookup on the destination table, and inserting the rows that don't exist instead?

Comment: I should run the reconciliation process then and there to check the data? I have almost 35 jobs running, should I embed this reconciliation process inside each of them?

Comment: Loading deltas is a very common approach usually in high volume shops. Not sure how you could know that some rows missing if there isn't a reconciliation in place already?

Comment: Yep, you should check for completeness of your data within your ETL process. Pls also be aware that it may not be the insertion that fails for certain records, but the select from the source side. Records may be locked.

Comment: @P.Salmon - The data was missing in the reports. That's how we go to know.

Comment: @Shadow - When you say records locked, what does it imply?

Comment: @RathiRao it implies that the select may not be able to read all records.